# discord.py - How to determine how much XP is left until the next level

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a leveling system, you have probably seen this for the hundredth time. I want a user to know how much XP is left until they reach their next level. I've tried many things, math, and all of that stuff, and they didn't work. They did give me numbers, but they were very inaccurate. One of them even gave me -3000. Literally. Does anyone know how to make it actually work? Please and thank you.

Code:

```
message_cooldown = {}

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        # Check if the user is in the cooldown dictionary
        if message.author.id in message_cooldown:
            current_time = time.time()
            last_message_time = message_cooldown[message.author.id]

            # Check if the user's cooldown has expired (0.5 seconds cooldown)
            if current_time - last_message_time < 1.5:
                if debug_mode == True:
                    print(f"Debug: Message sent too fast, not adding XP for user {message.author.name}. Server Name: {message.guild.name}")
                return

        with open('level.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        await update_data(users, message.author, message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel, message.guild)
        if debug_mode == True:
            print(f"Debug: 4 XP has been successfully added to user {message.author.name}. Server Name: {message.guild.name}")


        # Update the last message time for the user
        message_cooldown[message.author.id] = time.time()

        with open('level.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)


async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
  if str(user.guild.id) != '757383943116030074':
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      embed = discord.Embed(title=f" Level up!", description="{} has leveled up to **Level {}!**".format(user.mention, lvl_end), color=discord.Colour.green())
      await channel.send(embed=embed)
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end

@bot.command(aliases = ['rank','lvl'])
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
        with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
        exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']

        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
        embed.add_field(name="XP until next level", value=f"(idk) XP")
        embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar.url)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        if debug_mode == True:
            print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} checked their own level")
    else:
      # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
      with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
          users = json.load(f)
      lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
      exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
      embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP" ,color = discord.Color.green())
      embed.set_author(name = member, icon_url = member.avatar.url)
      if debug_mode == True:
          print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} viewed {member}'s level")

      await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: This must be a mathematical calculation. Explain how levels are calculated and we can deduce the formula. Help us help you. The way your question was asked, we need to analyze dozens of lines of code to understand how the levels are calculated...

Comment: on the level up event the next level is calculated by a division example (1/4), that calculates the XP it takes to the next level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the way you calculate the level, if you have the current level, you can find out the experience needed for the next level:

```py
current_lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
current_exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']

# lvl = int(exp ** 1/4)
# exp = lvl ** 4
next_exp = (current_lvl + 1) ** 4
missing_exp = next_exp - current_exp
```